# Animated object exported to fbx does not have any animation

Tags: animation, export, external-applications, unity

I have 2 animations currently on a sword that I have modeled and when I export the object as a fbx into my game engine Unity it seems to not bring the animations along with it. Here are the export settings: [image]

and here is what it looks like when imported into Untiy: [image]

As you can tell I am very new to blender and modeling in general so any tips on where I have gone wrong would be appreciated. Thanks! I apologize for the poor resolution on the second screenshot.

Comment: Can you share the model with the animations (the blend file). I just tried this on a cube with two keyframes using the default settings and it worked.

Comment: Heres a link to the file. Thanks https://www.dropbox.com/s/qs4cj3kw9wv7znu/weapon.blend

Comment: How do you take such a high resolution screenshot of the Blender UI?

Comment: Create your animations in Pose mode rather than Object and the problem is solved :)

Comment: just drag and drop the blend file to unity assets folder, it'll work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When exporting, tick *Include Default Take*. Also, since you aren't using bones, you should apply the scale on the model before exporting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *> Scale*).

[image]

The animation(s) should now come over with the selected one (in Blender) as the default take.

[image]

Comment: I had done that before but it doesnt take both of the animations over... I have two animations created called attackleft and attackright.. With this method i only get attackleft

Comment: @RileyShaw I don't think this is possible, it seems you have to export these on one timeline and split them up in Unity. See [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/34726/multiple-animations-in-the-same-fbxfile.html) and [this](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?249253-How-to-properly-export-animations-to-FBX).

Comment: @RileyShaw I don't think the format is the problem here. I dropped the blend file into Unity and it only came in with one animation. What most people do it seems is to create multiple files for the different anims.. `character.walk`, `character.run` etc or drop animations on a single timeline and split it up.

Comment: Ooooh ive got it now. I didnt realize that Unity has the option to split up one main animation into different animations. Thanks!

Comment: I this is a very old post but can you help me do this in blender 2.8 please? I'm trying to export a simple animation to unity but unity shows the black animation without any keyframes.

Comment: @ChiragMS You're right it's very old. See this video and the comments https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjflKgMepQs. Should be of some help.

Comment: @iKlsR Thanks much. It was very helpful. I appreciate your assistance.